# Critical values of the function $t^{3/4}-9t^{1/4}$

Tags: calculus

I would like to know the critical values of

$$t^{3/4}-9t^{1/4}$$

So far I have found $9$, but apparently there is another one.

Comment: Have you found the derivative of this function? What is it?

Comment: Never mind, I found the other one.

Comment: If you register your account (basically, choose a password for it), you'll be able to delete your post. To register, follow the link to user profile on top of the screen.